# Rails WEBrick server does not auto reload code in development environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am running WEBrick with the content of the `~/.rdebugrc` file being

```
set autolist 
set autoeval 
set autoreload
```

autolist and autoeval are turned on by default, but I need to get a debugger console and execute `reload` (or `set autoreload` from the debugging console once for each server session)  to have my changes reloaded, and even this doesn't reload some changes sometimes (I couldn't find what determines whether the source gets reloaded or not) and need to restart the server.

Anybody has any ideas to fix this and have autoreload on by default?

Thanks a bunch in advance.

Comment: I am running `bundle exec rails s --debugger`. I have to restart the server every time for it to pick up on the fact that I added/removed a `debugger` command from the code. Rails 3.2.0, ruby 1.9.3p0

Answer (score 3):

Judging by the minimal code Rails has for handling the `--debugger` option, I'd say this bug is more likely to be on the WEBrick side.

Try updating to ruby 1.9.3-p125 and see if the issue persists.